# How to load custom fonts to JsPDF with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jspdf

I'm trying to load a custom font to JsPDF in a typescript react app. I succeeded to add fonts by converting them to js modules, but I want to add them from .ttf file if possible.

I tried importing the .ttf file in the project, then load them with fetch, then use the following code:

```
pdf.addFileToVFS(fileName, dta)
pdf.addFont(fileName, family, style)
```

where **pdf** is an instance of **jsPDF**, **dta** contains the loaded .ttf file encoded in base64. It seems to be working, as when I use .getFontList() the loaded font is there, but immediately after adding the font, jsPDF throws the following error:

**PubSub Error No unicode cmap for font**

And then, the added font does not work. What can I do?